# how do I handle DEBUG level logs, raise their severity to INFO and log to stdout?

Tags: python, logging

I need to raise the severity of all debug logs in my script and log them as INFO. I was intending to use a handler for this. I am importing a package that logs at DEBUG level so I cannot change the original logging level. I need them to be logged as INFO in my script.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a file-specific logger. that way in your script you can set the severity level to DEBUG while keeping the logger in the package at its level.

In doing so you create the module logger and set its level instead of the root logger (which will demage the package's output)

This is an example of file-specific logger:

```
# this creates a logger specific for that "__name__" which is the name of your moduele
module_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
module_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

module_logger.log(...)
```

now you can use this logger to log while keeping everything else the same,

Hope that helped

Comment: I can't call the `.log` function myself in my script. The logging is being done already by the package I'm importing. I just need to handle those logs and increase their severity.

Comment: what do you mean "I need them to be logged as INFO in my script" then?